# Correct way to get require.js to play nicely in an older project

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm adding a new JavaScript project, already written using require.js, to an existing website.

The existing website already uses jQuery in some of its other code, and I'm getting some error messages from the existing code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'cookie'
```

It looks like my introducing jQuery as part of my require project is causing a conflict.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show more code? Did you remove your old version of jQuery?

Comment: This error means the cookie plugin is not defined. That's either because you didn't include it, you included it too early or late, or you included a 2nd version of jquery that overwrote the previous one.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the 2nd version of jQuery loaded by RequireJS that is causing the problem. Unfortunately I do need to load both versions (the existing site uses v1.3, and my JavaScript needs v1.9). How can I get around this?